# How can I suppress the prompt for the execution of initialization cells?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I would like to suppress the following super-annoying prompt that appears each time I exit the kernel and restart my computations:

[image: Do you want to automatically evaluate all the initialization cells in the notebook]

Which menu option do I need to tweak? (I have tried quite a few.)

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCellWarning.html

Comment: Can you please include a brief explanation of how to use that command? The documentation is not very helpful, and including `InitializationCellWarning -> False` at the top of the notebook did no avert the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can choose not to have initialization cells in your notebook, by right-clicking the cell bracket and uselecting "Initialization Cell"

[image]

Or, if you like having initialization cells but just want them to evaluate without asking, you can evaluate

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, InitializationCellWarning -> False]
```

Finally, if you want to turn off the evaluation of initialization cells altogether, evaluate

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, InitializationCellEvaluation -> False]
```

These settings are 'sticky' and should stay set after restarting.

Comment: Thank you very much!